# How to plot two curves with the same area under?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I doubt this is doable in `tikz`/`pgfplots` but maybe some expert could give me an idea.

I would like the area under the second graph to be the same as the one under the first graph (they are probability density function, the area under them should be equal to 1).

Moreover, I would like the gray zones to have the same area.

The second graph can have a slightly different shape, of course, the important thing is it has a "fat" right tail.

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\alfa,\lambda)=
      (\lambda^\alfa)*(\x^(\alfa-1))*exp(-\lambda*\x)/factorial(\alfa-1);}
      ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth},
    ticks=none,
    samples=300,clip=false,
    enlarge x limits={value=.04,upper},
    enlarge y limits=.12,
    name=gamma
]
\addplot[thick, smooth, domain=-9:9, name path=curva] {gammapdf((x+10),8,1)};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\addplot [fill=gray!30, draw=none, domain=3:9] {gammapdf((x+10),8,1)} \closedcycle;
\end{scope}
\draw (3,-.005) node[below] {$q_\alpha$} |- (axis cs: 3, {gammapdf(13,8,1)});
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:6.5,0.04)  {$1-\alpha$}; 
\draw[-Stealth] (unomenoalfa) -- (axis cs:4,0.007);
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:-2.5,0.04)  {$\alpha$}; 
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth},
    ticks=none,
    samples=300,clip=false,
    enlarge x limits={value=.04,upper},
    enlarge y limits=.12,
    at=(gamma.below south west),
    anchor=north west,
]
\addplot[thick, smooth, domain=-9:9, name path=curvastrana] coordinates {
    (-9,0) (-5,1) (.5,.1) (7,.1) (9,0)
    }; 
\draw (3,-.005) node[below] {$q_\alpha$} -- (3,1);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\clip (axis cs: 3, 0) rectangle (axis cs: 9, 3);
\addplot [fill=gray!30, smooth, draw=none]  coordinates {
    (-9,0) (-5,1) (.5,.1) (7,.1) (9,0)
    } \closedcycle;
\end{scope}
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:6.5,0.4)  {$1-\alpha$}; 
\draw[-Stealth] (unomenoalfa) -- (axis cs:7,0.03);
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:-4,0.4)  {$\alpha$}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very demanding math problem ... if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, I think you understood correctly, :)

Comment: Demanding math problems and talk of using Mathematica (below) indicate you might want to look into the `sagetex` package which gives you access to a CAS, called SAGE, which can do the computational heavy lifting. It can do integrals and the page [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/probability/sage/probability/probability_distribution.html?highlight=probability%20distribution#module-sage.probability.probability_distribution) has various fat tail distributions built into it so that calculating $q_\alpha$ will be relatively easy.

Comment: @DJP Thank you for the infos!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can deform functions without changing their normalization by [convoluting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) them. Unfortunately `pgfplots` cannot do integrals, so all I can offer is a poor cat's convolution. I just multiply the function by a linear combination of functions where one has the peaks at the "right" place and then adjust the coefficients in such a way that the integrals fulfill your requirements. The integrals are done by Mathematica. Different functions will lead to different plots. The following also uses the `fillbetween` library, which allows you to avoid having to plot the functions twice.

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=3cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={gammapdf(\x,\alfa,\lambda)=
      (\lambda^\alfa)*(\x^(\alfa-1))*exp(-\lambda*\x)/factorial(\alfa-1);
      h(\x)=1.62*pow(sin(\x*18),2)-0.07*\x;}
      ]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth},
    ticks=none,
    samples=300,clip=false,
    enlarge x limits={value=.04,upper},
    ymax=0.28,
    %enlarge y limits=.12,
    name=gamma
]
\addplot[thick, smooth, domain=-9:9, name path=curva] {gammapdf((x+10),8,1)};
\path [name path=B] (-10,0) -- (10,0);
\addplot [gray!30] fill between [of=curva and B,
        soft clip={domain=3:9}];
% \begin{scope}[on background layer]
% \addplot [fill=gray!30, draw=none, domain=3:9] {gammapdf((x+10),8,1)} \closedcycle;
% \end{scope}
\draw (3,-.005) node[below] {$q_\alpha$} |- (axis cs: 3, {gammapdf(13,8,1)});
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:6.5,0.04)  {$1-\alpha$}; 
\draw[-Stealth] (unomenoalfa) -- (axis cs:4,0.007);
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:-2.5,0.04)  {$\alpha$}; 
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-Stealth},
    ticks=none,
    samples=300,clip=false,
    enlarge x limits={value=.04,upper},
    ymax=0.28,
    %enlarge y limits=.12,
    at=(gamma.below south west),
    anchor=north west,
]
\addplot[thick, smooth, domain=-9:9, name path=curvastrana] {h(x)*gammapdf((x+10),8,1)};
\draw (3,-.005) node[below] {$q_\alpha$} -- (3,{h(3)*gammapdf((3+10),8,1)});
\path [name path=B] (-10,0) -- (10,0);
\addplot [gray!30] fill between [of=curvastrana and B,
        soft clip={domain=3:9}];
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:6.5,0.04)  {$1-\alpha$}; 
\draw[-Stealth] (unomenoalfa) -- (axis cs:4,0.007);
\node (unomenoalfa) at (axis cs:-4,0.1)  {$\alpha$}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The second peak should be after the `q_a` but I think I can adjust it by myself.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sample `sagetex` solution. The standalone environment is used so the 2 pictures are side by side. Note that the value of $q_{\alpha}$ is computed by SAGE and placed into tikzpicture environment.:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% use newest version
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
sigma1 = 1
alpha = .75

zeta = 0
sigma2 = 1
T1 = RealDistribution('gaussian', sigma1)
Q1 = T1.cum_distribution_function_inv(alpha)
T2 = RealDistribution('lognormal', [zeta, sigma2])
Q2 = T2.cum_distribution_function_inv(alpha)

####### SCREEN SETUP #####################
LowerX = -4.0
UpperX = 4.0
LowerY = -.250
UpperY = 1.0
step = .01
Scale = 1.0
xscale=1.0
yscale=1.0
#####################TIKZ PICTURE SET UP ###########
output = r""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"[line cap=round,line join=round,x=8.75cm,y=8cm]"
output += r"\begin{axis}["
output += r"grid = none,"
#Change "both" to "none" in above line to remove graph paper
output += r"minor tick num=4,"
output += r"every major grid/.style={Red!30, opacity=1.0},"
output += r"every minor grid/.style={ForestGreen!30, opacity=1.0},"
output += r"height= %f\textwidth,"%(yscale)
output += r"width = %f\textwidth,"%(xscale)
output += r"thick,"
output += r"black,"
output += r"axis lines=center,"
#Comment out above line to have graph in a boxed frame (no axes)
output += r"domain=%f:%f,"%(LowerX,UpperX)
output += r"line join=bevel,"
output += r"xmin=%f,xmax=%f,ymin= %f,ymax=%f,"%(LowerX,UpperX,LowerY, UpperY)
#output += r"xticklabels=\empty,"
#output += r"yticklabels=\empty,"
output += r"major tick length=5pt,"
output += r"minor tick length=0pt,"
output += r"major x tick style={black,very thick},"
output += r"major y tick style={black,very thick},"
output += r"minor x tick style={black,thin},"
output += r"minor y tick style={black,thin},"
#output += r"xtick=\empty,"
#output += r"ytick=\empty"
output += r"]"
##############FUNCTIONS#################################
##GRAPH OF FUNCTION 1
t1 =  var('t1')
x1_coords = srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)
y1_coords = [(T1.distribution_function(t1)).n(digits=6) for t1 in x1_coords]
output += r"\addplot[thin, NavyBlue, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x1_coords)):
    if (y1_coords[i])<LowerY or (y1_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output += r"(%f,inf) "%(x1_coords[i])
    else:
        output += r"(%f,%f) "%(x1_coords[i],y1_coords[i])
output += r"};"

s=var('s')
for s in srange(Q1,3,step):
    output += r"\draw[color=gray] (axis cs:%f,0)--(axis cs:%f,%f){};"%(s,s,T1.distribution_function(s).n(digits=6))

output += r"\node at (%s,-.1) {$q_\alpha= %s$};"%(Q1.n(digits=3)+.4,Q1.n(digits=3))
output += r"\addlegendentry{$T_1$}"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"

##FUNCTION 2 #########################################
output2 = r""
output2 += r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output2 += r"[line cap=round,line join=round,x=8.75cm,y=8cm]"
output2 += r"\begin{axis}["
output2 += r"grid = none,"
#Change "both" to "none" in above line to remove graph paper
output2 += r"minor tick num=4,"
output2 += r"every major grid/.style={Red!30, opacity=1.0},"
output2 += r"every minor grid/.style={ForestGreen!30, opacity=1.0},"
output2 += r"height= %f\textwidth,"%(yscale)
output2 += r"width = %f\textwidth,"%(xscale)
output2 += r"thick,"
output2 += r"black,"
output2 += r"axis lines=center,"
#Comment out above line to have graph in a boxed frame (no axes)
output2 += r"domain=%f:%f,"%(LowerX,UpperX)
output2 += r"line join=bevel,"
output2 += r"xmin=%f,xmax=%f,ymin= %f,ymax=%f,"%(LowerX,UpperX,LowerY, UpperY)
#output += r"xticklabels=\empty,"
#output += r"yticklabels=\empty,"
output2 += r"major tick length=5pt,"
output2 += r"minor tick length=0pt,"
output2 += r"major x tick style={black,very thick},"
output2 += r"major y tick style={black,very thick},"
output2 += r"minor x tick style={black,thin},"
output2 += r"minor y tick style={black,thin},"
#output += r"xtick=\empty,"
#output += r"ytick=\empty"
output2 += r"]"
t2 =  var('t2')
x2_coords = srange(LowerX,UpperX,step)
y2_coords = [(T2.distribution_function(t2)).n(digits=6) for t2 in x2_coords]
output2 += r"\addplot[thin, Orchid, unbounded coords=jump] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x2_coords)):
    if (y2_coords[i])<LowerY or (y2_coords[i])>UpperY:
        output2 += r"(%f,inf) "%(x2_coords[i])
    else:
        output2 += r"(%f,%f) "%(x2_coords[i],y2_coords[i])
output2 += r"};"
s=var('s')
for s in srange(Q2,4,step):
    output2 += r"\draw[color=gray] (axis cs:%f,0)--(axis cs:%f,%f){};"%(s,s,T2.distribution_function(s).n(digits=6))

output2 += r"\node at (%s,-.1) {$q_\alpha= %s$};"%(Q2.n(digits=3),Q2.n(digits=3))
output2 += r"\addlegendentry{$T_2$}"
output2 += r"\end{axis}"
output2 += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\sagestr{output2}
\end{document}
```

The output running in [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) is shown below with alpha at .75:
[image]

The documentation for sagetex on CTAN is [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex). Sage is not part of the LaTeX distribution so it needs to be installed on your machine or open a free Cocalc account (the easiest way). The sample solution is using SAGE built in probability density functions [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/probability/sage/probability/probability_distribution.html?highlight=probability%20distribution#module-sage.probability.probability_distribution) to do the calculation. Of course, SAGE can handle integration to deal with probability density functions that are not built in.